# Onclick Expand input Width

Tags: input, expand

I have a function that expand input with a given width, my problem is how to modify that function in order to be executed only when I have a input with value and input type different than type="submit". I don't want to use classes or ids for each input because I have a lot of input on my app.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/81/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want but, Can you not use the jquery val() function? Your  example modified..

```
$('input[type!="submit"]').focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val().trim() != "") { 
        $(this).attr('data-default', $(this).width());
        $(this).animate({
            width: 300
        }, 'slow');
    }
}).blur(function() { /* lookup the original width */
    var w = $(this).attr('data-default');
    $(this).animate({
        width: w
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: Question :), if the input is disabled the script is not applied any more, what must be done for disabled inputs ? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

i have updated the code http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/84/ need to use filter $('input[type!=submit]')